# Is it possible to write complex object to Firebase authentication custom claims?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am wondering if it is possible to write (and read back) a more complex object to Firebase's authentication custom claims. For instance:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {groups: {groupId1: true, groupId2: true}, sections: {sectionId1: true}});
```

The documentation mentions only storing key - value pairs, not objects. The reason why I need it is that `groupIds` and `sectionIds` are auto-generated values, so I would prefere to not mix them together.

I would like to read this claims later in (for instance) Realtime database security rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "mydata": {
      "$groupId": {
        ".read":  "auth.token.sections.sectionId1 === true"
        ".write": "auth.token.groups[$groupId] === true",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this allowed in Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store any JSON object in custom claims, up to the size limit of 1000 bytes.  It should be easy to try for yourself.

Comment: I am sorry for this question. I was just wondering if it is allowed, I didn't find it anywhere. Thank you for your answer.